Missing Few days data historical : Yahoo Finance API Python yahoo_fin
I am fetching historical data of forex pair from yahoo finance, and I am experiencing missing data of few days. Then I tried smaller version of code and I face same issue. Please help
stock_symbol = 'USDCHF=X'
#fine the timeframe
start_date = '2024-04-02'
end_date = '2024-04-03'

# Fetch the data
stock_data = get_data(stock_symbol, start_date, end_date)

Results :
    open    high    low close   adjclose    volume  ticker
2024-04-01  0.90507 0.90894 0.90490 0.90507 0.90507 0   USDCHF=X
2024-04-03  0.90757 0.90854 0.90725 0.90809 0.90809 0   USDCHF=X

I don't have 2nd april data. Please explain why and how can i get this. Yesterday night I was getting same data but now it is not there.

What does get_data() do?

it is a method in yahoo finance library and used to fetch data

Please edit your question to show where you're getting get_data() from. Also, if your start date is 2024-04-02 why does your output contain data for 2024-04-01 ?
